# Elixir - compare 2 lists and update the latest items

Tags: elixir

I have 2 lists:

```
alist = [ %{"a" => 1}, %{"b" => 2}, %{"c" => 3}]
blist = [ %{"a" => 3}, %{"c" => 4}]
```

What is the most effecient way of compare them and update `alist` if `blist` have new value?

Final result is something like:

```
[ %{"a" => 3}, %{"b" => 2}, %{"c" => 4}] #updated_alist
```

I know I should use `Enum.map/2`, but just can't wrap my head around that.

**Update01**
I might oversimplify my situation a bit in the above example.

My Real scenario is, I am getting the `JSON` data from website which are:

```
content_a = {content:[
{item: "apple", committed: false},
{item: "orange", committed: false}
]}

content_b = {content:[
{item: "orange", committed: true}
]}
```

And I want to updated it to:

```
updated_content = {content:[
    {item: "apple", committed: false},
    {item: "orange", committed: true} # <-- updated this.
    ]}
```

I did try `Map.merge`, but my final result is:

```
merged_content = {content:[
        {item: "orange", committed: true}
        ]}
#{item: "apple", committed: false} is missing
```

I am not sure what happen.

Comment: `Enum.map` is useful when you want to _translate_ a list: the output has the same number of elements as the input.  So it alone is not the solution to your problem.  Do you have a primary key for each object in the JSON?  e.g. does `item: "orange"` represent a unique element in the list of content?

Comment: I have downvoted the question for restating it with an incorrect elixir code. `{item: "orange", committed: true}` is an invalid tuple. I believe you meant a map there. The same is applicable for `{content:`. You even did not put an effort into explaining your problem, why would be bother to answer?

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Aleksei that the structure of your data seems strange.  If you instead used standard Keyword lists or standard Maps, you could avail yourself of the standard merge functions ([Keyword.merge/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Keyword.html#merge/2) or [Map.merge/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#merge/2))

E.g. merging keyword lists:

```
iex> alist = [a: 1, b: 2, c: 3]
[a: 1, b: 2, c: 3]
iex> blist = [a: 3, c: 4]
[a: 3, c: 4]
iex> Keyword.merge(alist, blist)
[b: 2, a: 3, c: 4]
```

E.g. merging maps:

```
iex> amap = %{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
%{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
iex> bmap = %{a: 3, c: 4}
%{a: 3, c: 4}
iex> Map.merge(amap, bmap)
%{a: 3, b: 2, c: 4}
```

Comment: I updated my question with a better explanation. Please review. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way would be to produce a map out of `blist` and use it while iterating through `alist` to avoid traversing the whole `blist` list every time.

```elixir
blist_map =
  for bmap <- blist, {k, v} <- bmap, do: {k, v}, into: %{} 
#⇒ %{"a" => 3, "c" => 4}

for amap <- alist, {k, v} <- amap,
  do: %{k => Map.get(blist_map, k, v)}           
#⇒ [%{"a" => 3}, %{"b" => 2}, %{"c" => 4}]
```

*Sidenote:* the structure of both `alist` and `blist` smells wrong. Why would you want to have lists of maps? Would not a bare map be a better choice? With a map one can do `Map.merge/3` after all.

---

An inefficient straightforward solution involving `Enum.map/2` would be:

```elixir
Enum.map(alist, fn map ->
  {k, _} = Enum.at(map, 0)
  Enum.find(blist, &match?(%{^k => _}, &1)) || map
end)
#⇒ [%{"a" => 3}, %{"b" => 2}, %{"c" => 4}]
```